# Register number is odd?

Tags: arm

I am trying to write a function to check if a content of a register is odd or even.

if the content of R0 is odd  I place 1 in R1

if the content of R0 is even  I place 0 in R1

I tried Something like

```
TST R0 , #0
MOVEQ R1 , #1
MOVNE R1 , #0
```

Comment: I think you are close but not quite there, look at the instruction pseudocode in the arm docs.   is the argument for tst the bit number or a mask you and with?  and then the z bit is set or not set based on what?  moveq means if z bit is set which normally means if the result was equal to zero.

Comment: and do you even need to do a test?  is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

`ubfx r1, r0, #0, #1`

which is equivalent to

`r1 = r0 & 1` will do the trick.

---

For ARMv4:

`and r1, r0, #1`

Comment: Hi Jake,  the instruction is not working.  ubfx  is not valid in ARM, it say.

Comment: `UBFX` is available from ARMv7. What's the target of yours?